# have a background image and/or geomap for my model in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are in the process of using forge APIs for our 3d models viewing in browser and subsequently will take up dashboard analytics, IOT integrations etc.

For now, we wish to have the following

1. have a background image for my model in viewer
2. Have a google map and place my model @ a location eg. Bellary, Karnataka a factory location (my client) for whom we are coming up with 3D models
3. My model should communicate to my web server and database for IIOT readings and the indicator on the model should be shown where there are abnormal readings received from IIOT device.

Answer (score 0):

Let me address your points individually below:

1. Please refer to [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664339/how-to-add-custom-background-in-autodesk-forge) and [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/transparent-background-viewer-long-last)
2. Please refer to [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/add-mapbox-google-maps-forge-viewer)
3. You can take advantage of [Data Visualization extension](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/overview/)