# near and far calculation in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

In Forge Viewer, the near and far calculation is done in an internal `updateCameraMatrices` method. In that method, there's a final heuristic to fine-tune the near value better near line 31320:

```
// One more attempt to improve the near plane: make it 1/100,000 of the distance of the
// far plane, if that's higher.
// See https://wiki.autodesk.com/display/LMVCORE/Z-Buffer+Fighting for reasoning.
// 1e-4 is generally good below, but inside Silver Cross we get a lot of near clipping. So, 1e-5.
dMin = Math.max(dMin, dMax * 1e-5);
```

In some BIM models I load in the viewer I can see Z-fighting for some viewing angles. If I change the value from 1e-5 (1/100,000) to 1e-4 (1/10,000) as noted in the comments, the z-fighting is gone.
This also seems like a much more appropriate value for large models (like buildings). It's maybe less suited for small-scale models like 3D CAD models.

Can I safely change this value to 1e-4 if all I intend to render is models in the scale of buildings (from Revit, Navisworks etc)?

Will the Forge Viewer allow to configure the near/far calculation in its API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you shouldn't modify this value directly in the `viewer3D.js` file. It's not recommended to do so. There also is no such API to modify this value as I know.

However, have you tried to change the bounds of the viewer? Here might be a similar case you can refer: [Adding a skybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093441/how-to-set-up-skybox-in-autodesk-forge/45135420#45135420)

If this doesn't match what you need, could you provide some snapshots and more detail information demonstrating this issue to me? If you do so, I 'm glad to pass it to our engineering team for further investigating. You can send those materials to `forge.help@autodesk.com` if it cannot be posted publicly.

**P.S. Please remove confidential information from anything you sent to us.**

Comment: How do I change the bounds of the viewer? I did check the world bounding box (drawed it via THREE.js) and it seemed very accurate.
Can you perhaps explain what does "Silver Cross" mean in the comment in my question?

Comment: In this blog, the answerer of the Adding a skybox, Philippe, has explained how to change the viewer bounds via `viewer.navigation.fitBounds()`, please take a look: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-skybox-and-camera-animation