# Forge elements missing in some direction

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

My model is a pipe line and this is the screenshot from IFC viewer
[image]

and this is the screenshot from forge viewer

[image]

You can see in the forge I can't see the full pipe line. When I zoom in or change the direction some parts will missing. It only happens when close to model.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be one of the pathological cases where, due to the extremely large extent of the 3D design, the viewer heuristic (which tries to optimize the near/far clipping planes to avoid precision issues) fails. What's the bounding box of your model (you can retrieve it using `viewer.model.getBoundingBox()`)?

To work around this, you could try the following:

- switch the camera from perspective mode to orthogonal
- set the near radius to 1 (`viewer.impl.setNearRadius(1)`) as suggested in this Stack Overflow discussion: [Autodesk Forge Viewer - Near and Far clipping issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771277/autodesk-forge-viewer-near-and-far-clipping-issues)

Comment: ```viewer.impl.setNearRadius(1)``` not work for me but just like the link you post ```viewer.impl.setNearRadius(50)``` works fine